# Query for login using multiple tables

Tags: php, database

I've been trying to figure out how to pull this off. I've tried join but it results to an error. I could have made it a single table but students and faculty tables have different fields in them so I couldn't really mix them up. Some fields would be blank for some users. I

Here are my tables:
faculty, students

fields for faculty are:
username
password
lname
fname
subject
department
accounttype

fields for students are:
username
password
lname
fname
grade
section
contact
birthday
guardian
guardiancontact
accounttype

I hope you can give me an idea.

```
    <?php

            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $pos="";

                    $con=mysql_connect("localhost", "john", "Ichthys030313!") or die ("Unable to connect!");
                    mysql_select_db('SoftEng') or die ("Unable to select database!");
                    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE Username = '$username' and Password = '$password'");
                    $count = mysql_num_rows($sql);
                    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
                    if($count == 1)
                    {
                            session_start();
                            $_SESSION['userID'] = $row['AccountType'];
                            $pos = $row['AccountType'];
                    }
                            if($pos=="Admin")
                            {
                                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                                    alert ('Welcome, $username')
                                    window.location.href='adminpanel.php';
                                    </script>";
                            }
                            elseif($pos="Faculty")
                            {
                                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                                    alert('Welcome, $username')
                                    window.location.href='list.php';
                                    </script>";
                            }
                            elseif($pos="Student")
                            {
                                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                                    alert('Welcome, $username')
                                    window.location.href='editstudent.php';
                                    <script>";
                            }

                    else{
                                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                                    alert ('Wrong Username or Password')
                                    window.location.href='index.php';
                                    </script>";
                        }
?>
```

Database Structure:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You need a `while` loop --- `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){...}` to iterate through `$row['column']`

Comment: How about the query? I need to select from two tables. How do I do it right?

Comment: I know you'd need a JOIN, but I'm not good at those at all. Something I've only actually started getting into slowly but surely.

Comment: What's the goal that you want to achieve? You didn't outline that in your question.

Comment: You also need to change `elseif($pos="Faculty")` to `elseif($pos=="Faculty")` and `elseif($pos="Student")` to `elseif($pos=="Student")` before you can go any further with a possible JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Start the session at the top like this.
Check the return value inside while loop.
Use Double equal for Comparision as single equal is for assignment operator. 
Read the comment where you find them in the answer

```
    <?php
 session_start();

            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $pos="";

                    $con=mysql_connect("localhost", "john", "Ichthys030313!") or die ("Unable to connect!");
                    mysql_select_db('SoftEng') or die ("Unable to select database!");
                    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE Username = '$username' and Password = '$password'");
                    $count = mysql_num_rows($sql);

                    if($count == 1){//Start the iff statment

                        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){//Start the while loop
                    {

                            $_SESSION['userID'] = $row['AccountType'];
                            $pos = $row['AccountType'];
                    }
                            if($pos=="Admin")
                            {
                                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                                    alert ('Welcome, $username')
                                    window.location.href='adminpanel.php';
                                    </script>";
                            }
                            elseif($pos=="Faculty")//Use double equal comparision operator
                            {
                                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                                    alert('Welcome, $username')
                                    window.location.href='list.php';
                                    </script>";
                            }
                            elseif($pos=="Student")//Use double equal comparision operator
                            {
                                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                                    alert('Welcome, $username')
                                    window.location.href='editstudent.php';
                                    <script>";
                            }
                        }

                    } else{
                                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                                    alert ('Wrong Username or Password')
                                    window.location.href='index.php';
                                    </script>";
                        }
?>
```

**Important Note:**mysql is depricated. Use mysqli or PDO

**For Mysqli**_ function check this link http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

**For PDO** Check this link http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

And if you want to **learn about operator** check this link http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php

Comment: You are right on many points, however OP wants to query two tables and a JOIN is required; something I'm not good at, unfortunately.

Comment: LOL! I can do some JOINS but to a certain extent. I've only been doing SQL for a year, give me a break hahaha!! funny guy ;)

Comment: I forgot to edit my query. The login table is where everything should be, but I had them seperated - for faculty and students. I know it should go something like this: SELECT username, password FROM faculty JOIN students WHERE ... I can't formulate the next. It is required to have something common in both tables when using JOINs right?

Comment: For now, in one table. Which is login. I've inserted infos for testing. But it gets complicated when the admin adds a student/teacher. They go into student/faculty table. Thus, making them impossible to login.

Comment: Yep. For now. But I want to remove that and get my info from faculty and students table.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'OUTER JOIN login ON login.Username=students.Username
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1 <-- What I got.